# .htaccess redirect to 404 page RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

Is there a way to enter a RewriteRule in the htaccess file to redirect to a 404 page if a certain folder/url path as been typed or reached?

For example, if I want every user to be redirected to a 404 page if they get to:
www.mydomain.com/abc or www.mydomain.com/abc/ or whatever that comes after "abc", even if that folder really exists, I do not want the users to be able to reach it. If they do reach it, I want them to see the 404 error page. *** Please note I am not looking to set up a custom 404 error page, I am looking for a way to redirect to the default 404 page.

How can I do it? Is it possible?

```
RewriteRule ^abc/(*)?$ [R=404,L]
```

And how can I do the same thing in php, redirect to a 404 error page? Once again I am not talking about setting a custom 404 page, I am talking about the default 404 page, to simply redirect a user to the 404 error page using php.

Comment: you can't remove or rename the folder?

Comment: Yes I can, but I don't want to. It's for a security issue.

Comment: You have a custom page not found?

Comment: htaccess in the folder abc with "deny from all"

Comment: Have you tried changing permissions such that the pages in /abc/ are not readable by the apache user, preventing the general public from accessing those pages?

Comment: I did try all of your solutions and they are all good so thank you for the suggestions. The one that best suits my needs is a RewriteRule that matches the folder and redirect it to a custom 404.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Instead of using `mod_rewrite`, you can do this with a `RedirectMatch` directive:

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/abc/.*$
```

Comment: RedirectMatch 404 "/abc*"  did the job. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Michal Wojciechowski Hi! I used your solution to prevent access to maindomain.com/addon.com. Do you know if it's possible to use it also for preventing access to addon.maindomain.com ? Pls See my question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268061/htaccess-redirect-to-404-addons-and-subdomains-stopped-working . Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I did this on my website:

```
RewriteRule ^404/?$ 404.php
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/404/
```

And on the root of my website I placed a `404.php` page to customize that page.