# Can I NOT send a HTTP 404 error on a 404 page?

Tags: php, .htaccess, get, http-status-code-404, server

So basically I have my website and I'm trying to make it compatible with everything.

You go to the page: /Page_Name

But the page Page_Name does not exist but the 404 page is what handles the the request. I'm almost using it as a PHP GET command.

Web browsers work, but some other scripts fail because HTTP returns 404.

How can I fix this without creating files for every page? Can I use the .htaccess file to make the "GET" command work without "?Name=Page_Name" ?

Comment: Are you trying to say that you wish to have a single file to handle all requests instead of having multiple files for multiple pages?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733647/htaccess-redirect-to-404-page-rewriterule

Comment: @anubhava Yes please.

Comment: @GiamPy Pretty much, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule as **catch all rule** in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Then inside `index.php` you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to check what the original URI is.