# How to redirect to 404 but keep wrong URL on address bar using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, errordocument

Using .htaccess, I am trying to redirect to `404` with following rules on my website which is working fine

```
RewriteEngine ON
ErrorDocument 404 thedomain.com/404
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

but as it is expected this is changing/redirecting the URL as well. For example with not having a file name called `dummy.php` the URL will redirect to `thedomain.com/404`.

How can I can keep the existing URL (`thedomain.com/dummy`) and redirect to `thedomain.com/404` like what is happening in WordPress 404 pages.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess redirect to 404 page RewriteRule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733647/htaccess-redirect-to-404-page-rewriterule)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but the URL still changing to 404. I added up the `RedirectMatch 404 ^/abc/.*$` to the end of rules, by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your `.htaccess` code like this:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /2021/404.php

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/2021/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

When you have absolute URL in `ErrorDocument 404` it will perform full redirect. However using a relative URL will only do an internal rewrite to prevent URL changing in browser.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Same old! URL also is changing

Comment: I just copied everything from here

Comment: I am also getting `Not Found` after clearing cache .`The requested URL was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: I even check it in another browser and is same. Yes `thedomain.com` is a folder in `DocumentRoot` BUT I have the `.htaccess` inside this folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227252/discussion-between-anubhava-and-behseini).